# Webstorm debugging with Chrome?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, webstorm

I am unable to debug at al in Chrome. I set it as my default broswer but when I try to debug, I see Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7930 in the Debugger window, but nothing happens (Chrome doesn't popup or anything). I have no idea how to trouble shoot this....any ideas?

Comment: What OS are you using?

I got it working on my Mac, but it wasn't really worth it. I just debug from within an-alternate chrome instance that allows access to local files.

Answer (score 0):

Well I could not figure out how the heck to get Webstorm to debug with Chrome and their support is extremely limited. So as a workaround and what may be better because its free , is use Eclipse with Chrome Developer tools. 
You are able to debug all the JavaScript files on your server and set breakpoints. I haven't stepped through while debugging, but this seems very promising. You could use Eclipse as well for the development of your corresponding HTML and css files or use in conjunction with Netbeans which is also free.  Very straightforward if you are familiar with Eclipse already:

[Eclipse with Chrome Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with, and believe me its worth checking out...another alternative is to use the  [Chrome developer Tools](http://paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/) ***Built into the browser***

You can debug javascript (add breakpoints and step into over, view variables), edit css and see your modifications in real time and save changes back to your file system. It also has a revision history for changes you make and you can revert back to any version! You can use use these Chrome developer tools in conjunction with the free Netbeans IDE where you can create your HTML, CSS & Javascript which has excellent code hinting / completion with Jquery support. You also add plugins to add more functionality.