# WebStorm debugging in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, karma-runner, webstorm

I am not able to debug my Karma unit tests in WebStorm. How can I fix it?

I see this message when I click the debug button:

[image: JetBrains IDE alert]

I checked [How do I know what's wrong](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/LiveEdit). chrome://extensions shows:
[image: JetBrains plugin enabled for Chrome]

Clicking 'background page' shows:
[image: Jetbrains plugin background page]

Answer (score 0):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479676/webstorm-debugging-with-chrome) showed answers which helped me realize the solution.

The problem was that the JetBrains plugin was trying to debug on port 63343 (not sure why). I noticed Webstorm was serving on port 63342.

[image]

To fix the port mismatch, I opened the chrome://extensions tab, found JetBrains IDE plugin, clicked "Options". This opened a new tab where I could adjust the port that the JetBrains IDE plugin was using. I set the port to be the same value that Webstorm was using, then I clicked Apply.

[image]